# typescript: continue javascript execution even if there is typescript error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, create-react-app

I'm using create-react-app with typescript. I don't want typescript to stop the javascript execution when a typescript error is caught, I want to get warned in the console but I don't the UI to be interrupted.

is it possible to configure `tsconfig` in such a way?

Comment: I think you must fix error. Not dismiss it.

Comment: @KevinM.Mansour I think I'm a big boy. I can decide when to dismiss error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this with create-react-app, you can edit your `.env` file to have the following:

```
TSC_COMPILE_ON_ERROR=true
```

For information on advanced configuration of create-react app, see [this page](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/advanced-configuration/).

Comment: great!! thanks! will accept this after the time limit!